# Parser for json-like format in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

At work they use a format similar to JSON but without quotes that looks like this:

```
{foo:{qux:1,quux:0}, bar:{}}
```

The reason they don't just use json is because the C# package `Newtonsoft.Json` can deserialize this like if it was regular json and it works. I need to use it in Php but `json_decode` is not as forgiving.

So here's my attempt at a simple parser:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar;


class NotJsonParser
{
    const STEP_NAME = 0;
    const STEP_VALUE = 1;

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return array
     */
    public static function parseNotJSON($string)
    {
        $generator = self::stringIterator($string);
        $data = self::parser($generator);
        return $data[''];
    }

    /**
     * @param \Generator $generator
     * @return array
     */
    private static function parser(\Generator $generator)
    {
        $data = [];
        $step = self::STEP_NAME;
        $name = '';
        $value = '';

        while ($generator->valid()) {
            $i = $generator->current();
            switch ($i) {
                case ' ':
                case "\n":
                    continue;
                case '{':
                    $generator->next();
                    $value = self::parser($generator);
                    $data[$name] = $value;
                    $step = self::STEP_NAME;
                    $name = '';
                    $value = '';
                    break;
                case '}':
                    if ($name) {
                        $data[$name] = $value;
                    }
                    return $data;
                case ',':
                    if ($name) {
                        $data[$name] = $value;
                    }
                    $step = self::STEP_NAME;
                    $name = '';
                    $value = '';
                    break;
                case ':':
                    $step = self::STEP_VALUE;
                    break;
                default:
                    if ($step === self::STEP_NAME) {
                        $name .= $i;
                    } else {
                        $value .= $i;
                    }
            }
            $generator->next();
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $str
     * @return \Generator
     */
    private static function stringIterator($str)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
            yield $str[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the usage:

```
>>> $result = \Foo\Bar\NotJsonParser::parseNotJSON("{foo:{qux:1,quux:0}, bar:{}}");
=> [
     "foo" => [
       "qux" => "1",
       "quux" => "0",
     ],
     "bar" => [],
   ]
```

How could I improve this? I know it really lacks error handling. I don't mind that the numbers stay as strings. Also the format never goes more than 2 levels deep. Whitespace between tokens is non important but there shouldn't be whitespace inside the keys (e.g.: `{foo bar: baz}` should be an error).

Also how should I encode it back from an array to a string? I was thinking just using `json_encode` and then removing the quote characters.

Answer (score 3):

The following workaround will wrap your keys and values with double quotes.  Such hacks will always be vulnerable to edge cases.  To avoid sprinting down a rabbit hole of possibilities (I can think of a few cases off the top of my head -- 1. keys/values already containing quotes 2. declared empty/null keys ...there will be more), I'll just provide a solution for your sample input.

For now, I'm using `\w` to ensure that the space before `bar` is not included.  There are several ways to do this action, but I would need to have intimate knowledge of your project data to develop the expression that I feel is "best / most robust".

If you discover any fringe cases that break this simple regex pattern, please update your question and I can create a patch.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7DI6S))

```
$unquoted_json = <<<NOTJSON
{foo:{qux:1,quux:0}, bar:{}}
NOTJSON;

$quoted_json = preg_replace('~\w[^:{},]*~', '"$0"', $unquoted_json);
$array = json_decode($quoted_json, true);
var_export($array);
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    'qux' => '1',
    'quux' => '0',
  ),
  'bar' => 
  array (
  ),
)
---
{"foo":{"qux":"1","quux":"0"},"bar":[]}
```

Comment: That's an interesting take on it. I'll try it and see if it is better than the other approach. Thanks.

Comment: The difficult thing about fabricated sample input is that we don't have a lot of certainty that the fabricated data is a true indicator of the quality of characters/data that can potentially exist in your actual project.  Does your project data only use letters and numbers as key/value substrings?  Might you have floats? indexed arrays? quotes?  Might your keys/values contain one of the delimiting characters (`{}:,`)?  Please improve your question by further clarifying the range of known/expected formats that the data may have.  I want to see you find resolution. Some feedback would help me.